# How to get all values/members of a type in a instance of an object

Tags: c#, reflection

This seems like it should be simple, but I am missing something.

I have a class like this:

```
class DataObject
{
   public MyEnum Member1 {get; set;}
   public MyEnum Member2 {get; set;}
   public MyEnum Member3 {get; set;}
   public MyEnum Member4 {get; set;}
   public MyEnum Member5 {get; set;}
   public char Member6 {get; set;}
}
```

And another class that holds an instance of this class. From that object, I want to get a list of all the MyEnum member values in that instance (ie `List<MyEnum>`) so I can check all of them without having to type each name again.

GetProperties just returns all the properties (with which I suppose I could do a Where query with typeof).

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your properties like this:

```
var properties = typeof (DataObject)
               .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
               .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof (MyEnum));
```

Then you can call `GetValue` method for your each `DataObject` instance and populate the `List<MyEnum>`

For example, if you have a `List<DataObject>` you can populate your `List<MyEnum>` like this:

```
var objectList = new List<DataObject>();
var enumValues = new List<MyEnum>();
foreach (var obj in objectList)
{
     foreach (var prop in properties)
     {
        enumValues.Add((MyEnum)prop.GetValue(obj));
     }
}
```

You didn't provide the other class but if the `DataObject` is a property of another class then you can get all `DataObjects` with `LINQ` like this:

```
var objectList = otherList.Select(x => x.DataObject).ToList();
```